# F# - Avoid repeating constraints

Tags: f#, constraints

With version 7, F# allows grouping and naming of SRTP constraints to avoid repetition. The problem with constraints repetition in general remains though:

```
type U() = class end

type A<'B, 'C when 
    'B :> A<'B, 'C> 
    and 'C :> U
    and 'B : (new: unit -> 'B)
    and 'C : (new: unit -> 'C)> (par) = class end 

let create<'W, 'V when 
    'W :> A<'W, 'V> 
    and 'V :> U
    and 'W : (new: unit -> 'W)
    and 'V : (new: unit -> 'V) >(url) = A<'W, 'V>(url)
```

this code is legal, however constraints need to be completely repeated which is annoying and error prone. Ideally I would like something like

```
type U() = class end

let constraint1 = constraint<'B, 'C when 
    'B :> A<'B, 'C> 
    and 'C :> U
    and 'B : (new: unit -> 'B)
    and 'C : (new: unit -> 'C)>

type A<constraint1> (par) = class end 

let create<constraint1>(url) = A<constraint1>(url)
```

Is there a way (today) to avoid or mitigate this constraints repetition in general?

Answer (score 1):

Seem that it is only possible to create constrained types for a single generic type parameter, because constrained type definition should eventually evolve to some generic type. So the only approach that works for me here is to decouple you constraint into 2 independent types per each type parameter and have a constraint class as a separate definition as well:

```
type U() = class end

type Constraint1<'B
    when 'B : (new: unit -> 'B)> = 'B

type Constraint2<'C when 
    'C :> U
    and 'C : (new: unit -> 'C)> = 'C

type ConstrClass<'B, 'C when Constraint1<'B> and Constraint2<'C>>(url) = class end

let create<'B, 'C when Constraint1<'B> and Constraint2<'C> and 'B:> ConstrClass<'B, 'C>>(url) = ConstrClass<'B, 'C>(url)
```